# How do you make Python wait so that you can read the output?

Tags: python, ide

I've always been a heavy user of Notepad2, as it is fast, feature-rich, and supports syntax highlighting. Recently I've been using it for Python.

My problem: when I finish editing a certain Python source code, and try  to launch it, the screen disappears before I can see the output pop up. Is there any way for me to make the results wait so that I can read it, short of using an input() or time-delay function?  Otherwise I'd have to use IDLE, because of the output that stops for you to read.

(*My apologies if this question is a silly one, but I'm very new at Python and programming in general.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `raw_input()` or `input()` you could log your output (stdout, stderr) to a file or files.

You could either use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, or just redirect `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`.

I would suggest using a combination of the `logging` and [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) if you want to log errors with their trace stack.

Something like this maybe:

```
import logging, traceback
logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\Temp\log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    #do some stuff
    logging.debug('I did some stuff!')
except SomeException:
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Here's an example of redirecting `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_out = sys.stdout  # save the original stdout so you can put it back later
    out_file = open(r'C:\Temp\out.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = out_file

    save_err = sys.stderr
    err_file = open(r'C:\Temp\err.txt', 'w')
    sys.stderr = err_file

    main()  #call your main function

    sys.stdout = save_out  # set stdout back to it's original object
    sys.stderr = save_err

    out_file.close()
    err_file.close()
```

I'm going to point out that this is not the easiest or most straight forward way to go.

Answer (score 3):

you could start in the command window. e.g.:

```
c:\tmp\python>main.py
```

adding `raw_input()` (or `input()` in py3k) at the end of your script will let you *freeze* it for until enter is pressed, but it's not a good thing to do.

Comment: Which means that I have to have both the command window and Notepad2 open at the same time, one for editing and one for the output, yes?

Comment: @user: suppose so, is it a problem?

Comment: My Python resides in "C:\Python31\python.exe". If I were to want to open a file, I would have to put that, and the file path after it, to open it in the command window. Is there any other shortcut I may use, perhaps?

Comment: @user: when you do default installation of python. it binds `*.py` files to the Python executable. You wouldn't need to do any extra work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "problem" with Notepad2, not Python itself.

Unless you want to use input()/sleep (or any other blocking function) in your scripts, I think you have to turn to the settings in Notepad2 and see what that has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a call to `raw_input()` to the end of your script in order to make it wait until you press Enter.